# Compiling errors with CUDA convnet library

Tags: c++, macos, cuda

i am trying to compile alex krizevsky cuda convnet library on my macbook pro with Geforce 320M and i hit a wall here, cant move past further this.

The compiling is stuck with this "uint not defined". 
How to fix this?

```
/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc -m64 -O3 --compiler-options '-fPIC' -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 -I/usr/local/cuda/include -I /usr/local/cuda/samples/common/inc -I./include -o obj/release/./src/memory.cu.o -c src/memory.cu
/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc -m64 -O3 --compiler-options '-fPIC' -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 -I/usr/local/cuda/include -I /usr/local/cuda/samples/common/inc -I./include -o obj/release/./src/nvmatrix.cu.o -c src/nvmatrix.cu
/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc -m64 -O3 --compiler-options '-fPIC' -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 -I/usr/local/cuda/include -I /usr/local/cuda/samples/common/inc -I./include -o obj/release/./src/nvmatrix_kernels.cu.o -c src/nvmatrix_kernels.cu
src/../include/nvmatrix_kernels.cuh(78): error: identifier "uint" is undefined

src/../include/nvmatrix_kernels.cuh(78): error: identifier "uint" is undefined

src/../include/nvmatrix_kernels.cuh(78): error: identifier "uint" is undefined

src/../include/nvmatrix_kernels.cuh(78): error: identifier "uint" is undefined

src/../include/nvmatrix_kernels.cuh(79): error: identifier "uint" is undefined

src/../include/nvmatrix_kernels.cuh(96): error: identifier "uint" is undefined

src/../include/nvmatrix_kernels.cuh(96): error: identifier "uint" is undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go over following steps

1. Add `#include <stdint.h>` in `nvmatrix_kernels.cuh`
2. If it doesn't work try to replace `uint` with `unsigned int`

P.S. Generally speaking, just check the `nvmatrix_kernels.cuh` probably some `#define` is not correct for Mac OS

Comment: i added stdint.h but not working :( i see these lines  in nvmatrix_kernels.cuh

`#if defined(_WIN64) || defined(_WIN32)
#define uint unsigned int
#endif`